# My Binary Search Algorithm Template Function is Always Returning False

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, binary-search, readfile

So I'm supposed to use the Binary Search template function to read elements from a file to an array and then allow the user to search for an element if it's in the array. The problem is that whenever I search for a number, it gives me a "not found" even if the element does exist in the file. I know it's better to leave the template functions in the header file, but since I had no idea how to sort the file so the binary search would work I put the functions in the main program to make it less confusing. think the problem is in the main() or the sort function, but to my limited knowledge I can't figure out where exactly and how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template<class elemType>
class orderedArrayListType
{
public:
    static const int length = 20;//Const length of array you can change it accordingly
    int list[length];
    int binarySearch(elemType const&)const;
};

template<class elemType>
int orderedArrayListType<elemType>::binarySearch(const elemType& item) const
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = length - 1;
    int mid;

    bool found = false;

    while (first <= last && !found)
    {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;

        if (list[mid] == item)
            found = true;
        else if (list[mid] > item)
            last = mid - 1;
        else
            first = mid + 1;
    }

    if (found)
        return mid;
    else
        return -1;
}

void main()
{
    std::fstream numberFile("text.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    orderedArrayListType<int> object;

    int number=0, a;
    int i = 0;
    int numberToSearch;

    while (numberFile >> a)
    {
        object.list[i] = number;//Initalizing the array
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Enter Number you want to search" << endl;
    cin >> numberToSearch;

    int output = object.binarySearch(numberToSearch);//Make search

    if (output>0)
    {
        cout << "Element found at Index: " << output << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Element not Found" << endl;
    }



}
```

And these are the contents of the text.txt file:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are setting all elements of the list to `0`:

```
while (numberFile >> a)
{
    object.list[i] = number;//Initalizing the array
    i++;
}
```

Instead, you should fill in the numbers read from the file:

```
while (numberFile >> a)
{
    object.list[i] = a;//Initalizing the array
    i++;
}
```

Then, it would be better if you would use the template parameter for the list, because else the template will only work for `int`:

```
template<typename elemType>
class orderedArrayListType
{
public:
    static const int length = 20;//Const length of array you can change it accordingly
    elemType list[length];
    int binarySearch(elemType const&)const;
};

template<typename elemType>
int orderedArrayListType<elemType>::binarySearch(const elemType& item) const
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = length - 1;
    elemType mid;
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra tip! I will keep that in mind for future programs since I only need Int values for now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in the binary search function but with  :

```
 while (numberFile >> a)
 {
    object.list[i] = number;//Initalizing the array
    i++;
 }
```

`number` is always 0.

One advice , change :

```
mid = (first + last) / 2;
```

to

```
mid=first + (last-first)/2
```

It avoids overflow. It's always a good programming practice to look for these cases as well.

Comment: I changes number to a and it worked! I followed your tip as well. Thank you for the overflow tip!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those tips I was able to run the program correctly. Here is the edited main() program code to make it extra clear for anyone who might stumble upon any problems with such a program.

```
void main()
{
    std::fstream numberFile("text.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    orderedArrayListType<int> object;

    int number=0, a;
    int i = 0;
    int numberToSearch;

    while (numberFile >> a)
    {
        object.list[i] = a;//Initalizing the array
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Enter Number you want to search" << endl;
    cin >> numberToSearch;

    int output = object.binarySearch(numberToSearch);//Make search

    if (output>0)
    {
        cout << "Element found at Index: " << output << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Element not Found" << endl;
    }



}
```

Note that the change was only made to the part where the array is initialized as user (alain) advised:

```
while (numberFile >> a)
    {
        object.list[i] = a;//Initalizing the array
        i++;
    }
```